# changing url when reloading containing passed value

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
if ($description==""){
    header("location:..\initNewProject.php?state=-1");
}
```

and the initNew project.php code :

```
if ($state==-1)
    echo"<script>alert(\"kindly fill out the description\");</script>";
```

the problem is when refreshing on this page the url stays the same and keeps popup the alert 
how can I return the url to default when refreshing ?

Comment: It goes to infinite loop. In Javascript put reurn false

Comment: sorry I did not understand , which loop ?

Comment: you can use session or cookies for set flag..